# how to write css for a specific breakpoint in angular material

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design, material-design, angularjs-material

I am trying to write CSS for a div, that should apply only when a particular breakpoint is hit, eg. sm, md or lg.

I'm using angular-material (https://material.angularjs.org).

I know that this can be done using media queries `@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }` but i'm looking for a angular-material way of doing this.

Comment: check layout section : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/layout/options

Comment: i've gone through this before...not sure how this solves my current problem

Comment: Or you can do : @media (min-width: $layout-breakpoint-xs) { like in bootstrap.

Answer (score 24):

I'm using the $mdMedia service for that, see:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.core/service/$mdMedia

Additionally you can use it in a template directly e.g. with an ng-class directive:

```
// In your controller: 
$scope.$mdMedia = $mdMedia;

// In your template: 
<div ng-class="{sm: $mdMedia('sm'), md: $mdMedia('md'), lg: $mdMedia('lg')}">...</div >
```

Comment: I have been including MaterializeCss implementation instead of Responsive Tables when it comes to using angular-material. Good pro tip!

Answer (score 2):

Adding custom css to a tag using material breakpoints, Say suppose i have a custom css like below:

```
.textLeft{
text-align: left;
margin-left: 24%;
}
```

and you wanted to add it to a h3 tag if it is a not a mobile device, then follow the below steps. 
 1. Add ngMaterial to module.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial']);
```

2. inject $mdMedia to controller

```
app.controller('TabCtrl', ['$scope','$mdMedia', function($scope,$mdMedia){
  var thisCtrl = this;
  $scope.$mdMedia = $mdMedia;
}]);
```

3. Now use the $mdMedia as described by Rob earlier:

```
<div ng-controller="TabCtrl" layout="column">   
<h3 ng-class="{'textLeft' : $mdMedia('gt-sm')}">
                        {{user.name}}</h3>
</div>
```