# How to change breakpoints for flex sizes in angular-material?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

Is there any way to change the default flex breakpoint dimensions (xs, sm, md, lg) from 600px, 960px, etc?

For example, instead of 600px I want to use 740px.

Comment: You can't, you probably have to write your own CSS for that. You might be able to re-use the angular-material-layout.(s)css

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create your own breakpoints, edit the existing ones, like here on [github](https://github.com/vhdirk/material/commit/64e204e5343f8a5c8f843addffc06f54d5126903)
2. Or look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880080/how-to-write-css-for-a-specific-breakpoint-in-angular-material) to create css specific breakpoints.